# Users are spamming the site with ChatGPT questions and answers

Tags: support, moderation, spam

Here's a question written by user [Madhankumar V](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/112559/madhankumar-v):

[Role and necessity of Redis, Varnish, and Elasticsearch in Magento 2: Local environment or server?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/368033/role-and-necessity-of-redis-varnish-and-elasticsearch-in-magento-2-local-envi)

The answer by user [Madhan V](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/104125/madhan-v) is blatantly copied and pasted from ChatGPT.

Similarly, all the other answers by Madhan V are clearly generated by ChatGPT.

Furthermore, the only question ever asked by Madhan V is answered by Madhankumar V and is also generated by ChatGPT:
[When using the ui component to create dynamic rows in Magento 2, the first line white space row is visible. What is the problem? Please elaborate](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359897/when-using-the-ui-component-to-create-dynamic-rows-in-magento-2-the-first-line)

It seems that these two users -- possibly the same person -- are involved in reputation farming using AI-generated questions and answers.

AI-generated content should be [explicitly banned as it is on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).

Comment: Definitely looks like a sockpuppet - perhaps a custom mod flag on one or both users to mention this, or a mod may see this and decide to take any required action

Comment: Yeah, literally the first thing I find when I type `is:a` into the search box: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/369274/. All three of the answers are GPT. I think it may be good to expand on this post and focus on the fact that this SE site needs an explicit policy rather than on this particular pair of users. Just a suggestion though.

Comment: Update: It looks like the first account was terminated.

Answer (score 1):

These can and should still be flagged.

The Stack Exchange policy of [Inauthentic Usage](https://magento.stackexchange.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage) under the Code of Conduct page states:

> Plagiarizing or copying content from websites, books, or other **online and offline tools** without proper attribution in a manner that violates our referencing standards.

This means that **any uncited ChatGPT content inherently violates the Code of Conduct and should be removed.**

This is further supported by Stack Exchange staff member Bella_Blue [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393682/):

> TL;DR: Yes, the current Inauthentic Usage policy prohibits posting AI-generated content without appropriate attribution.

That said, an explicit policy that covers *all* ChatGPT and other Generative AI content (cited or not) should still be made here, as [many other sites have done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384922/is-there-a-list-of-chatgpt-or-other-ai-related-discussions-and-policies-for-our).